# How to find all maximal palindromes in a large string

Tags: c++, palindrome

So I am trying to create a program to mind all maximal palindromes in a DNA sequence ( just a long string of the letters 'A' 'T' 'C' & 'G')
and after that I would need to copy those same steps and adjust it to find the complemented substrings. (where A is compliment to T and C to G and vise versa)

getting a little stuck at the start but I am trying to do this in as efficient a way as possible.

Can Manacher's algorithm be used to find all maximal palindromes or is it just the longest?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show some code...

Comment: Just curious - why do palindromes matter in DNA?

Comment: In bio research palindromes tend to be good points to cut dna to splice 2 copies of the same sequence from the center

Comment: Are you looking for "any algorithm that solves the problem" or are you actually planning on running this on, say, human genome, so it needs to be very efficient for very large sequences?

Comment: only for testing the subject and learning the programming. Will be used with strings ranging from a few hundred to a few thousand but should still be efficient so that it can be applied to later work that would likely be larger.

Comment: Can you explain precisely what you mean by "[f]ind all maximal palindromes"? (Maybe by showing a short example input-string and a full listing of what your program would print/return for that input?)